# Java Math library calculate log

Tags: java, math, logging

I have one formula,

```
Q = -10 log10(P)
```

If P = 0.01

```
Q = -10 * log10(0.01) = 20
  = -10 * log10(1/100) = -10 * log10(1) - log10(100) = -10 * ( 0 - 2 ) = 20
```

If P = 0.001

```
Q = -10 * log10(0.001) = 30
```

If P = 0.0001

```
Q = -10 * log10(0.0001) = 40
```

I want to give 0.01 as Insert and want to get output as 20 .

I tried to use java log method but it is confused.

Anyone knows how to express this formula in the java?

Thank you,

Comment: The formula is almost exactly what you've shown. I don't understand your confusion `-10 * Math.log10(P)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Math.log10:

```
double q = evalQ(0.001);
public static double evalQ(double p)
{
     return -10 * Math.log10(p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `Math.log10()` static method.  See the link here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10(double)